# RawRabbit.Pipe NameSpace

Tags: c#, rawrabbit

I'm trying to get a grip on ServiceBus architecture and I am using RawRabbit 1.10.4.
For this I am following an online course where RawRabbit is used.
In the Registration of Command Handlers, the following Extension Method is created, where the Methoc ctx.UseConsumerConfiguration is called.

The Extension method should be in RawRabbit.Pipe namespace, which is not available.
What is the nuget package I need to install, to get the extension methods, or has this extension method / namespace been removed in Version 1.10.4?

```
    public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task WithCommandHandlerAsync<TCommand>(this IBusClient bus,
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
        where TCommand : ICommand
    => bus.SubscribeAsync<TCommand>(msg => handler.HandleAsync(msg),
        ctx => ctx.UseConsumerConfiguration(cfg => cfg.FromDelaredQueue(q => q.WithName("XXX"))));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to install RawRabbit 2.0, and the latest version in Nuget Manager Package is only 1.10.4 something. 
However you can use Package Manager Console to install version 2 with following syntax

```
Install-Package RawRabbit -Version 2.0.0-beta9
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Same problem for me, but I don't see Extension method even referencing the latest package: 2.0.0.rc5

Comment: version 2.0.0.-beta8 is good enough. For me, it worked when I changed in the .csproj file  the target framework to netstandard2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to install the nuget package RawRabbit.Compatibility.Legacy 
then reference into your class the namespace  `RawRabbit.Compatibility.Legacy`
or install the package **RawRabbit.Operations.Subscribe** if you don't want to work with legacy code

Use `UseSubscribeConfiguration` instead of `UseConsumerConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

On the "Add Packages" dialog there is a "Show pre-release packages" checkbox you can tick, so the "Version" combobox will show the beta and rc releases as well.

[image: Add Packages dialog]